# Where Do I find the Python 2.7 Module plotly.express?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-18.04

Note, I all ready have the Ubuntu package installed for python-plotly:

```
python-plotly/bionic,now 2.2.3+dfsg-1 all [installed]
```

Given the following line:

```
import plotly.express
```

I get the following:

```
   import plotly.express
ImportError: No module named express
```

I'm running the Python 2.7.17 on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Python Documentations, The older versions of `plotly.py` didn't include the `plotly_express` module and the user had to install it separately. But since the release of the fourth version :

> Plotly Express is now part of Plotly.py version 4 and so the plotly_express module now just re-exports the contents of plotly.express

But you can still try `sudo apt-get install python-plotly_express` and that may make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed like a matter of matching the versions. It was a lot of trial and error for me so I hope this saves someone else some time.

```
sudo pip install requests==2.6.0
sudo pip install six==1.11.0
sudo pip install retrying==1.3.3
sudo pip install numpy==1.16.6
sudo pip install psutil==2.2.1
sudo pip install patsy==0.5.1
sudo pip install scipy==1.2.3
sudo pip install plotly==4.5.0
sudo pip install pandas==0.24.2
sudo pip install statsmodels==0.9.0
sudo pip install plotly-express==0.4.1
```